# How do I use Neo4jClient to get a Neo4j relation by its ID?

Tags: .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I can create a relation and I have its RelationshipReference.  But how do I get the rest of the relationship with payload and all?

With a Node I can just client.Get(nodeid) but AFAIK there is nothing similar for relations.

---

Is Gremlin the way to go? If so - could someone give me a hint as I am still trial-and-horroring on how to do it through Neo4jClient.

Comment: Please see if the answer to 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491221/how-do-i-retrieve-a-relationship-in-neo4j-graph-database 

helps you at all.

Comment: @ChrisSkardon Perfect - but now I get {"Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty."} instead. It doesn't help to add them manually to the relation and removing the <MyRelation> from ExecuteGetAllRelationshipsGremlin doesn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an extension method for the IGraphClient itself:

```
public static class GraphClientExtensions
{
    public static RelationshipInstance<T> GetRelationship<T>(this IGraphClient graphClient, RelationshipReference relationshipReference) where T : Relationship, new()
    {
        if(graphClient == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("graphClient");
        if(relationshipReference == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("relationshipReference");

        var rels = graphClient.ExecuteGetAllRelationshipsGremlin<T>(string.Format("g.e({0}).outV.outE", relationshipReference.Id), null);
        return rels.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Reference == relationshipReference);
    }
}
```

usage: (IsFriendOf is a Relationship derived class, Data just a POCO)

```
var d1 = new Data{Name = "A"};
var d2 = new Data{Name = "B"};

var d1Ref = graphClient.Create(d1);
var d2Ref = graphClient.Create(d2);
var rel = new IsFriendOf(d2Ref) { Direction = RelationshipDirection.Outgoing };
var relRef = graphClient.CreateRelationship(d1Ref, rel);

//USAGE HERE
var relBack = graphClient.GetRelationship<IsFriendOf>(relRef);
```

It's not ideal, but it does make your code a bit easier to read.
(Plus you don't need to know the nodes, just the relationship reference)

Answer (score 0):

As a variant of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491221/how-do-i-retrieve-a-relationship-in-neo4j-graph-database) I got this to work:

```
// Get every relation going out from the node we used as out-node
// when we created the relation.
var query = string.Format("g.v({0}).outE", fromNodeID);
var rels = _client.ExecuteGetAllRelationshipsGremlin<MyPayload>(
    query, null
);
// We can get too many so filter per ID.
var rel = rels.Single(r => r.Reference.Id == relID);
```

But this is not the way I want it to work.  I have an ID and the fastest would be to use it, wouldn't it?

I have tried

```
var rels = _client.ExecuteGetAllRelationshipsGremlin<MyPayload>(
    "g.e(42)", null
);
```

but all that happens is that I get Exception:

```
{"Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty."}
```

There isn't anything in the payload serialised to start with. (bug?)  Also: removing <MyPayload> doesn't help. So I don't think it is a deserialising problem; but that the result of the query "g.e(42)" isn't the same as "g.v(11).outE" mentioned as the working workaround.

(Neo4j version is 1.9.M04 and my Neo4jClient should only be a week and a half old.)

Comment: I *think* that the problem is that the 'ExecuteGetAllRelationshipsGremlin' method is looking for a collection of relationships, not just one, so the deserializer is attempting to get a collection, but you are only bringing back a single relationship.